# JS iframe-resizer sets height to 0 if width is below 510px

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm using the Javascript https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer to make the iframe always the same height as the content.

This works quite fine but for example on my phone it does not wor (< ~525px it sets height to 0px

You can see it on http://www.eckl.com/edentity/neuwagen (Logs are enabled).

--LOG--

[iFrameSizer][Host page: edentity-iframe] Checking height is in range 0-Infinity
jquery.responsiveiframe.js?1484233957:8 [iFrameSizer][Host page: edentity-iframe]

Checking width is in range 0-Infinity
jquery.responsiveiframe.js?1484233957:8

[iFrameSizer][Host page: edentity-iframe] Requesting animation frame
jquery.responsiveiframe.js?1484233957:8 [iFrameSizer][Host page: edentity-iframe]

IFrame (edentity-iframe) height set to 0px jquery.responsiveiframe.js?1484233957:8

[iFrameSizer][Host page: edentity-iframe] Hidden iFrame detected, creating visibility listener
VM19339:9 [iFrameSizer][edentity-iframe] Trigger event lock off

--END LOG --

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden iFrames can cause problems. Best to force trigger a resize when unhidding them.